# How to make WPF pop-up windows not be hidden behind main application?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, popup

In a WPF application, I have buttons which pop up instances of windows.

- I click the first button and the first window pops up correctly in **front** of the main application.
- I click the second button and the second window pops up correct in **front** of the main application. However, the **first** window now moves **behind** the main application. This is confusing and unexpected since it is often in the middle of the main application and thus **seems that it disappears** until the user moves the main application to find it hiding behind.

[image]

This is the **XAML**:

```
<Window x:Class="TestPopupFix.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1" Height="600" Width="800">
    <StackPanel>
        <Button Content="Open first popup" Click="Button_OpenFirst"/>
        <Button Content="Open second popup" Click="Button_OpenSecond"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

And this the **code behind**:

```
private void Button_OpenFirst(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Window window = new Window();
    TextBlock tb = new TextBlock();
    tb.Text = "This is the first window.";
    window.Content = tb;
    window.Width = 300;
    window.Height = 300;
    window.Show();
}

private void Button_OpenSecond(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Window window = new Window();
    TextBlock tb = new TextBlock();
    tb.Text = "This is the second window.";
    window.Content = tb;
    window.Width = 300;
    window.Height = 300;
    window.Show();
}
```

**What do I have to do to make the main application stay furthest to the back as I pop up new windows?**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To arrange windows in a visual hierarchy you have to set the `Owner` property of the child window to the parent window.

You can read more about [the `Owner` property on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.window.owner.aspx).

You should change your code into something similar to this:

```
Window parentWindow;

private void Button_OpenFirst(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  this.parentWindow = new Window();
  this.parentWindow.Owner = this;
  this.parentWindow.Show();
}

private void Button_OpenSecond(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  Window childWindow = new Window();
  childWindow.Owner = this.parentWindow;
  childWindow.Show();
}
```

Comment: I've been screwing around with z-orders for longer than I care to admit and this is ultimately what my problem was. Thanks.

Comment: I have been pulling my hair out over this for hours.  Good answer.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem, but hosting a WPF window in a WinForms form. In this situation, setting the owner got me  part of the way, but occasionally it was still going behind.

What I ended up doing in addition to that was wiring up the `Loaded` event on the WPF window and calling `Activate` as follows:

```
_window.Loaded += (s, e) => _window.Activate();
```