# Show WPF Popup with Application after Application was maximized

Tags: c#, wpf, popup, maximize

I have application on WPF.
That app has popup window.
When I open that popup, then minimize application, then maximize app - only popup will be shown.

What I want - show popup and application on background.

How to achieve this? Currently I have no ideas.

Comment: are you able to get this pop up to work at any time, just one time or not at all?  can you share your current code?

Comment: my initial thought would be to open a new thread on application startup, and then have it check something like this `if (this.Maximised) { //show popup}`

Comment: @SimonPrice, if I understand you right, then yes - after maximize popup works good. And after closing popup application is shown as expected

Comment: have you worked with threads and background tasks before?

Comment: have a look at this and should talk you through the basics of what you need to know https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=31tHiGD8X-A

Answer (score 0):

And solution is very simple - to prevent popup windows from being "separately" from Main Window, just set `Owner` property to your popup.

More details you can find here : [How to make WPF pop-up windows not be hidden behind main application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1443185/how-to-make-wpf-pop-up-windows-not-be-hidden-behind-main-application/1443686#1443686)